# Can we create a dictionary in member functions from the class variables in python?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have a class which initializes variables from a dictionary parameter. And the member function of this class in-turn has to access a dictionary with "keys" as class variables and "values" as the values, that those variables are initialized with. To illustrate I have taken a simple example to explain the context:

I can do that using vars(class instance) but is there any other way to do that ?

```
# my_dict with variable number of keys
my_dict = {"v1" : "23.5", "v2" : "54.6", "v3" : "67.8" }

class Area(object):

    def __init__(self, my_dict):
       self.length = my_dict.get("v1")
       self.bre = my_dict.get("v2")
       self.height = my_dict.get("v3")
       self.width = my_dict.get("v4") ## which should return None

    def calculate(self):

       ## I want to access the class variables as a dictionary here
       area_instance = Area(my_dict)
       area_dict = vars(area_instance)
       # do calculation using area_dict by iterating over the dict

       return calculated value
```

a = Area(my_dict)
print (a.calculate)

I am looking for Pythonic way to access class variables as a dictionary without creating 
that class instance.

Comment: Please correct your code so it is valid python.

Comment: Why are you creating another Area inside of `calculate`? Why not just use `self`? And do you even need a class here at all if you're just using a dictionary anyway?

Comment: This seems like it may be an XY problem. What are you actually trying to do, and why do you think repeately converting between instance variables and dictionaries is a useful way to do that? There is very likely a better way!

Comment: @Blckknght I have something much complex but I want to be able to iterate over the dictionary made up of class variables in the Class member function.

Comment: If you want to be iterating over dictionary values, you probably shouldn't be putting them in attributes of a class. Just pass the dictionary around.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a class (and it's attributes) try putting before the function @classmethod. this will make so that the first argument of the function is considered as the class. Hope it helps